# How to select rows until the sum of a column reaches N, where the column is of type TIME

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, time, sum

I would like to select enough audio calls to have 00:10:00 minutes of audio. I have tried to achieve this by writing the following SQL (postgres) statement

```
SELECT file_name, audio_duration
FROM (
    SELECT distinct file_name, audio_duration, SUM(audio_duration)
    OVER (ORDER BY audio_duration) AS total_duration
    FROM data
) AS t
WHERE
t.total_duration <='00:10:00'
GROUP BY file_name, audio_duration
```

My problem is that it doesn't seem to be calculating the total duration correctly.
I suspect this is due the audio_duration column being the TIME type.

If anyone have any hints or suggestions on how to make this query, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data.  What is the data type of `audio_duration`?

Comment: What is `duration` of type `time` and not `interval`? `time` stores a "moment in time", not a duration.

Comment: he writes that 'audio_duration' is of type TIME

Comment: The type of duration is of type time and not interval.

Comment: Use `interval` data type for duration. A song can be 4 minutes and 15 seconds, but not half past 4.

Comment: I understand that, but it's the wrong data type. To store a duration you should use `interval` - you can't sum up points in time (what is the sum of "8 in the morning" and "3 in the afternoon"?)

Comment: So, how would I store a column of durations correctly in postgres? Do I convert everything to the interval type? If I did so, how would the query look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really define that column to be an `interval`. A `time` column stores a moment in time, e.g. "3 in the afternoon".

However you can cast a single `time` value to an `interval`. You also don't need the window function to first calculate the "running total" if you want the total duration per file:

```
SELECT file_name, sum(audio_duration::interval) as total_duration
FROM data
GROUP BY file_name
HAVING sum(audio_duration::interval) <= interval '10 minute';
```

---

To permanently change the column type to an interval you can use:

```
alter table data
  alter duration type interval;
```

Comment: Will try to convert to interval and attempt your proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with @a_horse_with_no_name that Interval is the better datatype, but must admit that the Time datatype in not incorrect. While you cannot add (+) time datatypes you can SUM them. Summing time datatypes result in an interval, and produces the same result as summing corresponding intervals. Time besides being moment is also the interval from the beginning of day to that moment. [Demo (fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/anSYWDGPDVEKujyuUfdpqX/0)

```
with as_time (dur) as ( values ('10:34:45 AM'::time),  ('03:14:50 PM'::time), ('11:15:25 PM'::time))
   , as_intv (dur) as ( values ('10:34:45'::interval), ('15:14:50'::interval),('23:15:25'::interval))
select *
  from (select sum(dur) sum_time from as_time) st
     , (select sum(dur) sum_intv from as_intv) si;
```

BTW: The answer to the rhetorical question "what is the sum of "8 in the morning" and "3 in the afternoon"? Well it's 23:00:00.